# Add Category Filter to Mini Search on Top Bar Magento

Tags: magento2.2, filter, catalogsearch

I would like to add category filter on the top search box. I found the link with same task for magento 1 but i would really appreciate if anyone can provide any guidance for magento 2

https://community.rackspace.com/developers/f/7/t/917

Comment: have you got any solution for this?

Comment: yet i have not received any solution. i am still looking forward for the best solution!!